# send int in writeUTF in java

Tags: java, sockets

writeUTF function accepts string. Is there any way to pass integer?

```
 OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
 int count = 8;
 dos.writeUTF((count); //Error on Sending integer value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dos.writeInt(count)` or `dos.writeUTF(String.valueOf(count))`

Comment: how to write boolean value?

Comment: @Irfan Wattoo: how about looking by yourself? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

What i normally do for such things is

```
 dos.writeUTF(""+count);
```

(There is not space between double quotes.)

This is a better way rather than writing a function.

So ""+count converts the expression to a string which can directly be read on the other side by

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(dis.readUTF());
```